# Раздельная компиляция шаблонных классов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужно разбить шаблонный класс на хедер и .cpp
Как это сделать?

Comment: Никак. Реализация шаблонных методов должна быть в h-файле, потому что в каждом cpp-файле, который подключает ваш h-файл, создаётся отдельная копия класса на основе типов, которые используются как параметры шаблона.

Comment: В общем случае — никак. Есть пара частных, правда. Вам это для чего нужно?

Comment: @ixSci нужно написать бинарное дерево, проблема в том, что я видел реализацию вектора на шаблонах, разбитого на .h и .cpp  https://github.com/shotInLeg/SVector тут

Comment: Ну, Вы посмотрите код по ссылке — он в `main` включает `svector2.cpp`: да, так можно делать. Но, на мой взгляд, это глупо, т.к. от такого «разделения» крайне мало пользы, а вот проблемы он создаёт. Делайте своё дерево в одном заголовке, чем Вас это не устраивает?

Comment: Отрицательный ответ — тоже ответ. Кто-нибудь, опубликуйте?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае, так сделать нельзя. Можно, конечно, разделить код на 2(а можно и на 10) файлов, только потом придётся включать все файлы, в которых содержится код шаблона.

Альтернативным вариантом, является такой, при котором в заголовке перечисляется все варианты шаблонного параметра — тогда можно смело выносить реализацию в .cpp. Но при этом теряется универсальность шаблонного класса.